# Is there any ESAPI alternative for doing SQL injection and XSS validation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, esapi

Is there any other alternative for preventing the SQL injection and XSS attacks ? I know ESAPI can you be implemented for JAVA 1.5 or higher versions, my project is on JAVA 1.4 and need to implement the ESAPI, preventing from SQL injection and XSS attacks, any other alternative libraries for JAVA 1.4 is also helpful.

Comment: You should not use java4 anymore. It is not supported since more than 10years

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other alternative for preventing the SQL injection and
>   XSS attacks ?

SQL:  Java [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) have been around since 1.2.  And speaking as co-owner of the ESAPI-java-legacy repo, you should be using those instead of ESAPI for proper defense.  The SQL escaping technology provided by ESAPI was only intended to give emergency relief to eventually be replaced with parameterized queries.

XSS:  None that I would trust.  I'm pretty sure that apache commons StringEscapeUtils has dependencies on libraries that have known vulnerabilities.

> my project is on JAVA 1.4 and need to implement the ESAPI, preventing
>   from SQL injection and XSS attacks, any other alternative libraries
>   for JAVA 1.4 is also helpful.

Well, the next release that should be hopefully out by the end of September 2017 stops supporting Java 1.6.  The ESAPI 1.4 version that would still possibly work with 1.4 has known CVEs on it that will never be fixed.  ESAPI at the time of 1.4, was the only public library in the world that did what it did.

As an aside:  Any application ***that*** old that's still in production probably has worse problems in it than a library like ESAPI could fix.